# Excel - Record how many items a customer buys

Tags: excel, count, sum, formula

I need your expertise for this specific area.

I'm running customer/inventory record on my excel but I don't know how to count the number of items a customer buys in times. For example there're 2 columns: Customers and Stocks.

```
08 Jun -- William -- When Breath Becomes Air -- $9.00
                  -- A Long Way Home -- $12.99
                  -- Other Stationaries -- $5.99  

20 Sep -- William -- Annual service -- $50
```

So I tried creating a column to manually insert the number of items each time that customer buys and use IF-SUM-VLOOKUP. But that's just exhausting:

```
08 Jun -- William -- 3 -- When Breath Becomes Air -- $9.00
                       -- A Long Way Home -- $12.99
                       -- Other Stationaries -- $5.99  

20 Sep -- William -- 1 -- Annual service -- $50
```

Next, I guess I can do a little bit of SUMIF but it requires customer name to appear the exact time whereas I merge my customer cells cause I want it to be neat and clear to record. So merge and SUMIF don't fit well. Urgh!

```
08 Jun -- William -- When Breath Becomes Air -- $9.00
       -- William -- A Long Way Home -- $12.99
       -- William -- Other Stationaries -- $5.99
```

I just wish there's any way that can record a customer purchasing time so I could give them rewards and discounts whenever they reach a certain purchasing threshold. I'm open up with suggestions, and thanks guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of items a customer buys, you can use this formula entered in `C2` cell `=IF(B2="","",IFERROR(LARGE(F2:$F$800,COUNT(F2:F800)-1)-ROW(),1))`. also, you need helper column (`F` column) in which you should enter this formula and drag it to the bottom `=IF(A1<>0,ROW(),"")`. Please see result in picture below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your solution, but when another customer buys in a same day it would break the formula, so this solution is applicable but partially.

Comment: you're welcome. Actually, that shouldn't break formula, just tried that and it's counting inputs right...Could you please elaborate what another customer means regarding structure of data?

Comment: I'm just afraid with another customers appearing in the column our formula would not be able to handle it, since the C column formula isn't quite related with customers' names. So if I use this with mixed numbers of customers, it would still count normally? Furthermore, I don't know why but when I use the ROW function for F column it shows really big numbers like 98 100 or so, my date format is DD/MM/YY. Thank you so much.